# My font icons disappears on carousel change using Owl Carousel

Tags: carousel, compass-sass, owl-carousel

Basically I have styled buttons with attached icons using the :before sudo element (SASS)

```
.btn {
    @include font-size-px-rem(14px); //font-size
    @include box-sizing(border-box);
    background-color: $yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    color: $black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 26px 8px 11px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;

    @extend .arial; //my font

    -webkit-appearance: none;

    &:hover,
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        color: $white;
        background-color: $light-blue;
    }

    &:before {
        @extend .icon__right-big; //font-Icon
        @include font-size-px-rem(15px); //font-size
        position: absolute;
        right: 8px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -8px; //vertically align icon - middle (half font height)
        z-index: 2;

    }
}
```

This creates my button right and everything works pretty much perfect.

The challenge is when using OwlCarousel. I have a button in every listed Carousel which still displays right on desktop but doesn't mobile.

Onload it renders the first set of button with the font-icons but when on-sliding to the next carousel, It show button but font-icon disappears on slide complete. Button arrow flickers each time I change the active carousel either by sliding or clicking the next arrow.

I have google the internet and haven't found anyone with the same issue.

I have tested this on both **Android(Nexus 4)** and **iPhone(5s)** and I was going to assume it being a rendering issue but I don't know what to think or how to get this resolved.

Any help will do.

Answer (score 2):

commenting out the `overflow: hidden;` on the animated element which in my case if the `.btn` solves it.